# Converter float ou double em $ real

Tags: java

Tenho um `float = 11.6` quero converter em moeda brasileira `R$ 11,60`, alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eu normalmente utilizo o getCurrencyInstance com o Locale definido manualmente porque quando eu não defino ele pega o horário do Sistema Operacional e pode certamente fará uma conversão errada de real para dólar por exemplo.

```
Double d = 10.1;
Locale ptBr = new Locale("pt", "BR");
String valorString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(ptBr).format(d);
System.out.println(valorString);
```

Answer (score 6):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer, por exemplo:

```
BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal ("12000000.12");  
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();  
String formatado = nf.format (valor);
System.out.println(formatado);
//O resultado é R$ 12.000.000,12
```

Outra opção:

```
Long a = Long.parseLong("999999999999999999");
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(a));
//saída R$ 999.999.999.999.999.999,00
```

Comment: O NumberFormat é confiável? Se eu for usar no Android a depender das configurações do usuário isso pode variar não?

Comment: dá um olhada na documentação do android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: @MateusCarvalho Variará se vc não usar o Locale. De outra forma não vejo problema.